# Flutter aab file to Google Play Console - The Android App Bundle was not signed

Tags: android, flutter

Maybe I'm not understanding this right, but when creating a bundle using `flutter build appbundle --release` and choosing `Releases signed by Google Play` means that you don't have to sign the bundle locally and Google handles the signing for you when uploading the aab file.

I'm not sure what to do to get Google to sign the bundle when it's being uploaded.

This is the buildType release from `android/app/build.gradle`

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.test.app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Comment: Can you share the Android/app/build.gradle file so we can get a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create an upload keystore**

keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks ^
-storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 ^
-alias upload

Create a file named [project]/android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore. Don’t include the angle brackets (< >). They indicate that the text serves as a placeholder for your values.

```
storePassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyPassword=<password-from-previous-step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<keystore-file-location>
```

you can get better idea from https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: So wait ... I don't understand ... I still have to create a keystore file if Play Store will sign the bundle and create apks from it?

Comment: yes. you have to follow the all steps given in  https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android